# Jmeter user session wise different data set

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing, threadgroup

My test plan is as following

```
- Test Plan
    - Thread Group (No of Threads: 4)
        - HTTP Request Defaults
        - HTTP Cookie Manager
        - CSV Data Set Config(Login Information) [4 user login]
        - Simple Controller
            - HTTP Request(GET: Open Login Page)
            - HTTP Request(POST: Login auth)
            - Loop Controller
                - CSV Data Set Config(Operation Information) [8 operation data]
                - HTTP Request(GET: Open Operation page)
                - HTTP Request(POST: Commit Operation)
            - HTTP Request(POST: Logout)
```

In this plan suppose I provide 4 users and 8 operation data.
What it doing is running 8 operation for 4 users each in total of 8x4=32 operations.

How could I make this as following

```
1st user will do 2 operations
2nd user will do 2 operations
3rd user will do 2 operations
4th user will do 2 operations
```

I want to provide user session wise different operations that 4 users will do number of transactions but the transactions will not be same.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the loop count of the Loop Controller and in the Thread Group?

Comment: Give 4 as the loop count in the Thread group and 2 in the Loop Controller.

Comment: Also, please mention which 2 operations should be the user considered. User 1 will do first two operations, User 2 should do third and fourth operations and so on.

Comment: loop count is currently 1 for both thread group and loop controller. Trying your second reply, I will let u know. And your third is as u said. I could provide different data set for each users. But it would be better if users could pick data as u said in third reply.

Comment: Tried as your second. But it gives 32 transaction. 4 users with thread group loop count 4 and loop controller loop count 2 gives 4x4x2 = 32 transactions.

Comment: Is this what you are expecting? http://imgur.com/a/74bjK

Comment: Yes and I made it by interleave controller.

Comment: I didn't use interleave controller :)

Comment: Please share your solution..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142456/discussion-between-esty-and-naveenkumar-namachivayam).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting your test scenario correctly you can just set the "Sharing Mode" of your [CSV Data Set Config (Operation Information)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to `Current Thread Group`.

> **Current thread group** - each file is opened once for each thread group in which the element appears

---

If you want more precise control I believe [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) is what you're looking for, using it you can select which user will go for which execution branch.

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more information.

Comment: You r correct about using current thread group. Let me read your links. i will let you know.

Comment: Thanks & solved. I didn't use switch controller but my purpose served by Interleave controller. I checked `Interleave across threads` option and it provides children to different threads.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, I am posting my solution. Below is the test plan story.

### Test Plan

[image: My Test Plan]

### Thread Group

I used only 1 thread in my thread group and 4 in the loop count as shown below.

[image: Thread Group]

### Loop Controller

[image: Loop Controller]

### CSV Config for the both the files

[image: CSV Config]

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: 1 thread will not serve my purpose. I need to increase threads for concurrent transaction.

Comment: @Esty Please check the CSV Data Set Config

Comment: checked but if I keep threads at 1 then will this `All Threads` csv makes concurrency?